# Increase USB 2.0 power by adding buck converter to motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, motherboard

I'm thinking about adding more power to my laptops USB 2.0 ports, by hooking it up to a buck converter witch takes its input directly from the power connector of my laptop.

The voltage and current supplied by the charger are 19V ~4A and this is the voltage i would supply the buck converter to and then get 5V out of it and as much current as possible (i don't think the current is going to be an issue though since i wont need more than 2A anyway) and then connect these 5V to the USB power lines, i hope you get the picture!

I don't want to use a powered USB hub because its not practical and i need another power supply for no real reason as it seems.

Did anyone do something similar and do i need to pay attention to something while doing this (i don't want to mess up the ports since they are kind of custom and harder to find, and that applies to the on board hub also), thanks.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? A little help with the bigger picture might be useful.

Comment: In the second paragraph of my post i explained why id want to do this, its basically more convenient looks better and is more portable since im doing this on a laptop.

Comment: What USB device are you using that won't work with the power normally supplied by the laptop's USB ports? You can get USB leads which have two connectors on the computer end to draw power from two USB ports.

Comment: Im using a PlayStation 2 controller to USB converter, (the blue one) and it works fine as long as i have vibration disabled but as soon vibration gets in the 60% range it kicks out and i get an error massage saying that the USB device is malfunctioning but as soon vibration gets below ~60% it kicks back in.

Comment: @AndrewMorton has the right answer: you can power the 5V line from somewhere else entirely as long as it uses the same ground. Don't back-power the port itself.

Comment: @pjc50 thats exactly what i wanted to do same ground of course since it all comes from one power supply and no backpowering. So i guess thats all there is to it?

Comment: This project may not be meaningfull since \$V_{USB}\$ pin of the USB Hub is probably supplied from a converter which has a Maximum output power. I did not try to measure the short circuit current of my USB hub(because I am a poor guy that can not do experiments which can do harm to my PC), but if you wanna do this, you should start by checking the Short path current of your USB.

Comment: Solution,  get a bluetooth controller

Comment: @Passerby what good would a Bluetooth controller be?

Comment: @adoion battery powered, no voltage sag from current drain when the rumble feature goes off.

Comment: Right, that probably is the best thing to do here, get a dualshock 3 or something :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. You'll likely damage the internal 5 V supply in the USB port by 'back-feeding' it from the additional supply.

If the additional supply powers up *after* the motherboard one, then before it powers up, it'll act as a load on the motherboard, and possibly the USB port will be disabled by its own internal protection. Conversely, if it remains powered *after* the motherboard is shut down, likely the motherboard won't be happy.

Comment: its not fed from the motherboard its directly hooked up to the power supply, and im going to cut the back-feed to the motherboard supply

Comment: I agree with @adoion that nothing in your post precludes finding an answer to the question.